# Getting string literal from a generic object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This function gives me a type with an index of `[x:string]` instead of `myKey`:

```js
const myObj = {
  key: "myKey",
  otherStuff: {stuff:3}
}

type SomeObj<T extends string> = {key: T} & Record<string, any>

function makeObject<TKey extends string, TEntry extends SomeObj<TKey>>(entry: TEntry){ return {[entry.key]: entry} 
}

const result = makeObject(myObj)

/// type of result is const result: {
///    [x: string]: {
///        key: string;
///        otherStuff: {
///            stuff: number;
///        };
///    };
/// }
```

Same thing for the type of `key` in the result object.  Why is it losing the type information and how can I get it back?

(I realize I can force it to read the literal by declaring `key: "myKey" as const`, but that's not what I want.  I want to infer it in the function, if possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to infer exact return type, you should overload your function or use type assertion. I prefer the first way. Consider this example:

```js
function makeObject<TKey extends string, TEntry extends SomeObj<TKey>>(entry: TEntry): Record<TEntry['key'], TEntry>
function makeObject<TKey extends string, TEntry extends SomeObj<TKey>>(entry: TEntry){
    return {
        [entry.key]: entry
    }
}

const result = makeObject(myObj)
```

However, it is still does not work. SInce, `myObj` is mutable object, TS infers `key` as a string.

Here you have also two options. You either make your object immutable using `as const` or use literal object as an argument.
First approach:

```js
const myObj = {
    key: "myKey",
    otherStuff: { stuff: 3 }
} as const
```

Second approach:

```js
const myObj = {
    key: "myKey",
    otherStuff: { stuff: 3 }
}

type SomeObj<T extends string> = { key: T } & Record<string, any>

function makeObject<TKey extends string, TEntry extends SomeObj<TKey>>(entry: TEntry): Record<TEntry['key'], TEntry>
function makeObject<TKey extends string, TEntry extends SomeObj<TKey>>(entry: TEntry) {
    return {
        [entry.key]: entry
    }
}

const result = makeObject({
    key: "myKey",
    otherStuff: { stuff: 3 }
})
result.myKey // myKey
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVgkvm)
I have noticed that people don't like using `as const` assertion.

TypeScript always infers computed property as a string and not as an exact key. This is by the default.

---

Consider this exmaple with error

```js
function makeObject<TKey extends string, TEntry extends SomeObj<TKey>>(entry: TEntry): Record<TEntry['key'], TEntry> {
    // error Type '{ [x: string]: TEntry; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<TEntry["key"], TEntry>'.(2322)
    return {
        [entry.key]: entry
    } 
}
```

Return value `{[entry.key]: entry }` has indexed type as `{[prop:string]:...}`. It means that `prop` might be any string whereas according to return type `key` can be only `TEntry['key']`. Hence, `{[prop:string]:...}` might be considered as a supertype of `Record<TEntry['key']>` and supertype is not assignable to subtype.

I have used overalodaing, because it is bivariant. It means that it compiles if it assignble to function signature or function signature assignable to overloading type. In our case, `{[prop:string]:...}` is not assignable to `Record<TEntry['key']>`, but `Record<TEntry['key']>` is assignable to  `{[prop:string]:...}`.

Overloading are not so strict, that's why it works. Usually if return type contains generic from input, TS will complain. In order to fis sucj cases you usualy need to overload your function.

Comment: Thanks.  I had forgotten about the inference of string once you put it in an object.  The problem with `as const`, IMO, is just that it's easy for consumer (i.e., other developers) to forget.

Comment: BTW, I'm familiar with the assertion method in this scenario, but how does your overload work.  I see that it does, I'm just curious as to why that works and why simply making it a return type on a non-overloaded function (not an assertion) doesn't work.

Comment: @sam256 made an update

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_constraints you can find more explanation why generic from input might not work as a return type